# understanding self in C-Objective with "Start Developing iOS Apps Today" tutorial example

Tags: ios, objective-c

I just started to study C-Objective- and programming with Xcode for Iphone.

Now - i am trying to understand how app "Start Developing iOS Apps Today" works.

[Here is link for this app](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/RoadMapiOS/ThirdTutorial.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011343-CH10-SW1)  .

There i have piece of code in the file XYZAddToDoItemViewController.m:

```
@interface XYZAddToDoItemViewController ()

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *textField;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *doneButton;

@end

@implementation XYZAddToDoItemViewController

-(void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if (sender != self.doneButton) return;
    if (self.textField.text.length > 0) {
        self.toDoItem = [[XYZToDoItem alloc] init];
        self.toDoItem.itemName = self.textField.text;
        self.toDoItem.completed = NO;
    }
}
```

i have one question - in this case self is pointer to XYZAddToDoItemViewController class? or pointer to what?

Comment: its a pointer to the instance of a XYZAddToDoItemViewController class, so when an object of type XYZAddToDoItemViewController is made, when that code executes, it will have a reference to itself... `self`

Comment: Check This link https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/general/conceptual/devpedia-cocoacore/ClassMethod.html

Comment: First off, it's "Objective-C".  That's a proper name and should not be rearranged in any language.

Comment: Why does this have 3 comments, 2 answers, and no close as duplicate votes?

Comment: thank you Foenix for the answer it helped me a lot. And you was right Hot Licks about C-objective - i just corrected it. Sorry if my question was alredy answered.

Comment: @nhgrif - We like to beat up the OP a little bit first before we close the question.

Answer (score 0):

In an instance method of a class, `self` is a pointer to a class instance.